# ProFTPD with AD LDAP dont retrieve right usergroup

Tags: ftp, ldap, authentication

I am struggling with a ProFTPD with AD LDAP auth.
I have everything configured and the AUTH works, it retrieves de user from the AD and if it exist, it creates the home folder and let he user in.

The problem is, the folders are created with UID and GUID that exist on the LDAP, in that case, my user has UID 10001 and GUID 512, so the folder belongs to 10001.513

This is not the right scenario, because it means, the user can log in but can not upload or do anything so for me it is useless.

Maybe someone could throw me some info.

Now, the logs and conf files.

Server: ubuntu 14.04 LTS

```
Proftpd: 1.3.5a with mod_ldap 2.7

proftpd.conf

Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

UseIPv6             on
IdentLookups            off
ServerName          "FTP Server"
ServerType          standalone
DeferWelcome            off
MultilineRFC2228        on
DefaultServer           on
ShowSymlinks            on
TimeoutNoTransfer       600
TimeoutStalled          600
TimeoutIdle         1200
DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
DisplayChdir                .message true
ListOptions                 "-l"
DenyFilter          \*.*/
DebugLevel          9
AllowOverwrite          on
RequireValidShell off
DefaultRoot         /nas
Port                21

<IfModule mod_dynmasq.c>
</IfModule>
MaxInstances            30
User                proftpd
Group               nogroup
Umask               022  022
AllowOverwrite          on
TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log
<IfModule mod_quotatab.c>
QuotaEngine off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ratio.c>
Ratios off
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_delay.c>
DelayEngine on
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls.c>
ControlsEngine        off
ControlsMaxClients    2
ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log
ControlsInterval      5
ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c>
AdminControlsEngine off
</IfModule>

<Directory /home/%u >
        AllowOverwrite          yes
        <Limit ALL>
                AllowAll
        </Limit>
</Directory>
<Directory /home/public >
        AllowOverwrite          yes
        <Limit ALL>
                AllowAll
        </Limit>
</Directory>

Include /etc/proftpd/ldap.conf
Include /etc/proftpd/tls.conf
Include /etc/proftpd/conf.d/
```

ldap.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ldap.c>
AuthOrder   mod_ldap.c
LDAPServer  ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
LDAPAttr    uid         sAMAccountName
LDAPAuthBinds   on
LDAPBindDN  "CN=faxsync,OU=it,DC=doman,DC=local" "*******"
LDAPUsers   "OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local" (&(uid=%u)(objectclass=user))
LDAPGroups  "OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local"
LDAPAttr    gidNumber   primaryGroupID
LDAPDefaultUID  65534       
LDAPDefaultGID  65534
LDAPGenerateHomedir on 0700
CreateHome on 0700
LDAPGenerateHomedirPrefix /nas/home
LDAPForceGeneratedHomedir on

</IfModule>
```

And the relevant logs (sanitized)

```
2015-04-02 12:27:28,601 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user)) from template (&(uid=%u)(objectclass=user)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,601 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: attempting connection to ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
2015-04-02 12:27:28,601 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set protocol version to 3
2015-04-02 12:27:28,601 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: connected to ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
2015-04-02 12:27:28,603 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: successfully bound as CN=faxsync,OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local with password (see config)
2015-04-02 12:27:28,603 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set dereferencing to 0
2015-04-02 12:27:28,603 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set query timeout to 5s
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr sAMAccountName
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr uidNumber
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr primaryGroupID
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr homeDirectory
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults...
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: using default homedir /nas/home/nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr loginShell
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: user nunterberger, uid 10001, gid 513, homedir /nas/home/nunterberger, shell /bin/sh
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup)) from template (&(primaryGroupID=%v)(objectclass=posixGroup)) and value 513
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no entries for filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local from template OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,622 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user)) from template (&(uid=%u)(objectclass=user)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr sAMAccountName
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr uidNumber
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr primaryGroupID
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr homeDirectory
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults...
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: using default homedir /nas/home/nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr loginShell
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: user nunterberger, uid 10001, gid 513, homedir /nas/home/nunterberger, shell /bin/sh
2015-04-02 12:27:28,624 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup)) from template (&(primaryGroupID=%v)(objectclass=posixGroup)) and value 513
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no entries for filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: couldn't determine group name for user nunterberger primary group 513, skipping.
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(memberUid=nunterberger)(objectclass=posixGroup)) from template (&(memberUid=%v)(objectclass=posixGroup)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(memberUid=nunterberger)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no entries for filter (&(memberUid=nunterberger)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_shaper
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): ROOT PRIVS at mod_shaper.c:2026
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): RELINQUISH PRIVS at mod_shaper.c:2028
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_wrap2
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_ban
2015-04-02 12:27:28,625 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_wrap
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_radius
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_delay
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching PRE_CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: successfully unbound
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: not unbinding to an already unbound connection.
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): dispatching CMD command 'PASS (hidden)' to mod_auth
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local from template OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user)) from template (&(uid=%u)(objectclass=user)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: attempting connection to ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set protocol version to 3
2015-04-02 12:27:28,626 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: connected to ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
2015-04-02 12:27:28,627 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: successfully bound as CN=faxsync,OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local with password (see config)
2015-04-02 12:27:28,627 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set dereferencing to 0
2015-04-02 12:27:28,627 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set query timeout to 5s
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr sAMAccountName
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr uidNumber
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr primaryGroupID
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr homeDirectory
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults...
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: using default homedir /nas/home/nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr loginShell
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: user nunterberger, uid 10001, gid 513, homedir /nas/home/nunterberger, shell /bin/sh
2015-04-02 12:27:28,629 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup)) from template (&(primaryGroupID=%v)(objectclass=posixGroup)) and value 513
2015-04-02 12:27:28,630 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,630 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no entries for filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,630 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local from template OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,630 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user)) from template (&(uid=%u)(objectclass=user)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,631 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,631 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr sAMAccountName
2015-04-02 12:27:28,631 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr uidNumber
2015-04-02 12:27:28,631 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr primaryGroupID
2015-04-02 12:27:28,631 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr homeDirectory
2015-04-02 12:27:28,631 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults...
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: using default homedir /nas/home/nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr loginShell
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: user nunterberger, uid 10001, gid 513, homedir /nas/home/nunterberger, shell /bin/sh
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup)) from template (&(primaryGroupID=%v)(objectclass=posixGroup)) and value 513
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no entries for filter (&(primaryGroupID=513)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: couldn't determine group name for user nunterberger primary group 513, skipping.
2015-04-02 12:27:28,632 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(memberUid=nunterberger)(objectclass=posixGroup)) from template (&(memberUid=%v)(objectclass=posixGroup)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,633 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(memberUid=nunterberger)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,633 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no entries for filter (&(memberUid=nunterberger)(objectclass=posixGroup))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,633 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): no supplemental groups found for user 'nunterberger'
2015-04-02 12:27:28,633 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local from template OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,633 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: generated filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user)) from template (&(uid=%u)(objectclass=user)) and value nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: searched under base DN OU=it,DC=domain,DC=local using filter (&(uid=nunterberger)(objectclass=user))
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr sAMAccountName
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr uidNumber
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr primaryGroupID
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr homeDirectory
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: no values for attribute homeDirectory, trying defaults...
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: using default homedir /nas/home/nunterberger
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: fetching value(s) for attr loginShell
2015-04-02 12:27:28,634 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: user nunterberger, uid 10001, gid 513, homedir /nas/home/nunterberger, shell /bin/sh
2015-04-02 12:27:28,635 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: attempting connection to ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
2015-04-02 12:27:28,635 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set protocol version to 3
2015-04-02 12:27:28,635 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: connected to ldap://ldap.domain.local/??sub
2015-04-02 12:27:28,635 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set dereferencing to 0
2015-04-02 12:27:28,635 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): mod_ldap/2.9.3: set query timeout to 5s
2015-04-02 12:27:28,636 fileserver proftpd[4163] fileserver.domain.local (3VQVB5J.local[192.168.13.22]): user 'nunterberger' authenticated by mod_ldap.c
```

Hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the culprit here is that your `ldap.conf` file has *both* `LDAPGenerateHomedir` *and* [`CreateHome`](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/CreateHome.html):

```
LDAPGenerateHomedir on 0700
CreateHome on 0700
```

Only one of these directives is needed to actually create home directory.  The `CreateHome` directive is the newer, more recommended path; the howto to which I linked has more examples/descriptions of what you can do with it.  Thus you might try commenting out `LDAPGenerateHomedir`, and seeing if `CreateHome` does what you need.

Hope this helps!